# On eigenvalues and eigenvectors of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Question**

The derivative $\frac {df(x)} {dx}$ of a single variable function is a linear operator on the vector space of smooth functions, that is, functions in one variable where any number of derivatives are always well-defined. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this linear operator?

**My working**

From the definition of an eigenvector, we know that the eigenvector of the linear operator must be a non-zero function $f(x)$ such that
$$\frac {d} {dx} f(x) = \lambda f(x),$$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar. In other words, $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the linear operator if and only if there is non-trivial solution $f(x)$ that satisfies the above equation. Now, I can only think of two forms of $f(x)$ that satisfy the above equation:

1. $f(x) = a$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and the derivative is always zero. In particular,
   $$\begin{aligned}
   \frac {d} {dx} a & = 0,\\
   \implies \frac {d} {dx} f(x) & = 0f(x),
   \end{aligned}$$
   so there is only one eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ and the eigenvectors $f(x) = a$ can be any constant polynomials function, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $f(x) = e^{ax}$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and the derivative is
   $$\begin{aligned}
   \frac {d} {dx} e^{ax} & = ae^{ax}\\
   \implies \frac {d} {dx} f(x) & = af(x),
   \end{aligned}$$
   so the eigenvalues are $\lambda = a$ and the eigenvectors $f(x) = e^{ax}$ can be any exponential function, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Am I correct so far? I am also not sure whether other kinds of functions satisfy the equation above. Any intuitive explanations or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct and you have obtained all solutions: every real number is an eigen value. You can also obtain all eigen vectors as follows:  $\frac  {df} {dx}=\lambda f(x)$  implies that the derivative of $e^{-\lambda x} f(x)$ is $0$ (by product rule). Hence, $e^{-\lambda x} f(x)=c$ where $c$ is a constant. So $f(x)=ce^{\lambda x}$. Take $c \neq 0$ so that $f$ is not the zero function.